# How to prevent GUIs from interfering with each other when multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I've been a program in Java that is used to process images. During this image processing, though, the swing GUI that is running at the same time (and includes a progress bar and such) simply freezes until the processing is complete. I've tried multithreading the program to solve this problem, letting the processing run in the background, but it doesn't seem to work.

Below is some of my code that I've been using.

```
public class GUIThread implements Runnable {
    public static final int CHOOSER_HUB = 0;
    public static final int LAUNCH_IMAGE_PREVIEWER = 1;
    public static final int DISABLE_PREVIEWER_BUTTONS = 2;
    public static final int MEMORY_USAGE_WINDOW = 3;
    private int guiNumber;

    // ==========================================================================
    // |                               START CODE                               |
    // ==========================================================================

    /**
     * Runs begins the thread. This method is also for pre-run configuration,
     * but so far there is none of that.
     * 
     * @param GUINumber
     *            The GUI number, indicating which GUI to start.
     */
    public void start(int GUINumber) {
        DebugMessenger.out("Starting new thread for GUI");
        guiNumber = GUINumber;
        run();
    }

    /**
     * Starts the thread, and runs a method determined by what guiNumber was set.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        DebugMessenger.out("Thread running");
        if (guiNumber == GUIThread.CHOOSER_HUB)
            createChooserHub();
        if (guiNumber == GUIThread.LAUNCH_IMAGE_PREVIEWER)
            createPreviewer();
        if (guiNumber == GUIThread.DISABLE_PREVIEWER_BUTTONS)
            disablePreviewerButtons();
        if (guiNumber == GUIThread.MEMORY_USAGE_WINDOW)
            createMemoryUsageWindow();
    }

    /* More code, including methods called by run() */

}
```

To start my program, I simply run the following code.

```
public class Main {
    /**
     * Main method. Starts the threads and lets them roll.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start threads
        DebugMessenger.out("Starting Main");
        GUIThread guiThread = new GUIThread();
        guiThread.start(GUIThread.LAUNCH_IMAGE_PREVIEWER);
        if(Config.DEBUG_OUTPUT_ENABLED) {
            memBarThread = new GUIThread();
            memBarThread.start(GUIThread.MEMORY_USAGE_WINDOW);
        }
        DebugMessenger.out("Main complete");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I made the multithreading about as simple as possible, but it still seems that when I run the program and the image previewer begins processing, the memory usage window freezes. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

One important thing that you are missing in your code which will become the bottleneck is that in Java, you never invoke `run`() by yourself **(if you do that it will NOT create a separate Thread, rather it will run in main thread itself)**, rather you will create a `Thread` object and start that `Thread` (using start method as below) so that it will invoke the `run`() method in a separate thread as shown below:

**GUIThread Class:**

```
public class GUIThread implements Runnable {
    public static final int CHOOSER_HUB = 0;
    public static final int LAUNCH_IMAGE_PREVIEWER = 1;
    public static final int DISABLE_PREVIEWER_BUTTONS = 2;
    public static final int MEMORY_USAGE_WINDOW = 3;
    private int guiNumber;


    public void setGUINumber(int GUINumber) {
        this.guiNumber = GUINumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        DebugMessenger.out("Thread running");
        if (guiNumber == GUIThread.CHOOSER_HUB)
            createChooserHub();
        if (guiNumber == GUIThread.LAUNCH_IMAGE_PREVIEWER)
            createPreviewer();
        if (guiNumber == GUIThread.DISABLE_PREVIEWER_BUTTONS)
            disablePreviewerButtons();
        if (guiNumber == GUIThread.MEMORY_USAGE_WINDOW)
            createMemoryUsageWindow();
    }

    /* More code, including methods called by run() */

}
```

**Main Class:**

```
public class Main {
    /**
     * Main method. Starts the threads and lets them roll.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start threads
        DebugMessenger.out("Starting Main");

        GUIThread guiThread = new GUIThread();
        guiThread. setGUINumber(GUIThread.LAUNCH_IMAGE_PREVIEWER);

         //Create and Start the Thread now using Thread API
         Thread threadObj = new Thread(guiThread).start();

         if(Config.DEBUG_OUTPUT_ENABLED) {
            memBarThread = new GUIThread();
            memBarThread.start(GUIThread.MEMORY_USAGE_WINDOW);
        }
        DebugMessenger.out("Main complete");
    }
}
```

You can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using multithreading at all with the code you've provided.

You start by calling `GUIThread.start(int)`, regardless of input this calls `run()` which I guess is method doing blocking work. Nowhere is a new thread created and told to begin executing independently.

I suggest you look into the following concepts:

- Concurrency in Swing and the Event Dispatch Loop: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html
- Executors: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html
- Threads: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Answer (score 0):

Your GUI freezes because the actions are still running in the Swing GUI thread.

Let the GUIThread class extends `Thread` (instead of implementing `Runnable`) and call the Thread's `start` Method.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Changed the first line to `public class GUIThread extends Thread {`, renamed the `start()` method to `startThread()`, and replaced `run()` with `start()`.

Comment: @user119567: I'm glad to help you.

Comment: You can start a Thread with a Runnable.  It's better to implement Runnable than extend Thread.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc In the most cases you are right. You can pass it to a Thread (e.g. `new Thread([your Runnable]).start();`) or to an executor (e.g. `Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit([your Runnable]);`).